# Mixed WebForms/MVC Web Api application very slow when hosted on IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, configuration, webforms, asp.net-web-api

I have got a mixed WebForms/MVC Web Api application which I host on IIS 7.0. It has two main pages – Default.aspx and Main.aspx. And all the rest is done via WEB api calls/JSON/javascript. It works fine on my local machine, but we are experiencing some problems when we publish it on the server.

It looks like it randomly ignores connections to the server. Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes will just never load and eventually browser will show network connection error. During these “blind” time-slots working process that hosts the app won’t do anything – just like it is not receiving any input from IIS/client. In next 10 minutes it will work fine again. Although I do not see any pattern here, it seems that it is more stable when I address it using direct link to a page: `http://webserver/AppX/Default.aspx`  or `http://webserver/AppX/Main.aspx`

At the very same IIS server another application which is webforms app works just fine. They are in different application pools – the only difference is the second app is hosted in Classic mode, while the first one in Integrated. Switching it to Classic mode doesn’t help.
I suspect it has something to do with routing, and mixed nature of the application.

I studied several similar cases I found here on stackoverflow and already tried following:

1. Switch application pool to enable 32 bit apps. I compile everything
   for Any platform so it works (when it works) in 64 bit mode too.
   Didn’t help.
2. I told the router to ignore any aspx pages:

   ```
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");
       routes.IgnoreRoute("");
       routes.IgnoreRoute("Images/favicon.ico");

       var route = routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
   ```
3. In case if requests bypasses one of the ignores above there is a default
   controller that redirects it back to Default.aspx:

`public class HomeController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Index()
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unused);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri("Default.aspx", UriKind.Relative);
            return response;
        }
    }`

1. Just in case I increased a number of maximum connections to 500 in web.config

Nothing of mentioned above helped. Any ideas, what else I can try? Thanks.

Comment: Did solve this problem already?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend turning on failed request tracing on your IIS server.

http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Also, check your IIS logs and HTTPError logs on the server for hints on what could be going wrong.